# rails 2.3.5 upgrade to rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.8

I have a project on old framework Rails 2.3.5 & ruby 1.8.6 ,which is running on window 7 and Server mongrel.
Now i want to upgrade rails framework to rails 5 on Linux platform.

Is there any tool available for this. as manual work is too long process.

Comment: on word : better to re-write.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: Yes, you're going to have a hard time. :) The most problematic segment is rails 2 -> 3. The rest is easier.

Comment: Also, there are companies that do this for a living. Maybe hire one of those. Found this one: https://www.upgraderails.com/

Comment: Hi mahtab. are u looking for any free tool to convert?

Comment: Yes,Just need to online tool to convert rails 2.3.5 to rails 5.

Comment: haven't tried but you could check: https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade And yeah, going from 3 to 4 would be easier

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no tool to do upgrade 2.3.5 to 5. Neither can this be done in 1 step. If you don't want to rewrite from scratch or pay a 3rd party for it, assign enough time to it and start upgrading version by version.
It can be accomplished, just requires a lot of patience.